# How to connect to Azure CosmosDB using resource token via Mongoose library?

Tags: azure, mongoose, azure-cosmosdb

It seems to me almost all [CosmosDB samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-samples) rely on username and password (a.k.a "master key") to connect to the DB.

However when client cannot be trusted to use the master key it is recommended to use [resource tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/secure-access-to-data#resource-tokens) to securely connect to CosmosDB.

So the question is: is it possible to use [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/) to connect to Azure CosmosDB using resource token?

Comment: Resource tokens are used to limit the scope of the access that a master key token would normally give you. This doesn't make it a recommended way but rather a different use case.

Comment: Good point. I've just updated the question to clarify that.

Answer (score -1):

> is it possible to use Mongoose to connect to Azure CosmosDB using
>   resource token?

Of course yes. Based on the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/secure-access-to-data#resource-tokens), you could generate resource token via a Mid-Tier Service. Resource token generation and management is handled by the native Cosmos DB client libraries; however, if you use REST you must construct the request/authentication headers.

So, you need to create [User](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/create-a-user) and [Permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/create-a-permission) to generate resource token in Mid-Tier Service.Please refer to my sample Java code:

```
import com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.*;

public class CreatePermission {

    private static final String END_POINT = "https://***.documents.azure.com:443/";
    private static final String MASTER_KEY = "***";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception, DocumentClientException {

        DocumentClient documentClient = new DocumentClient(END_POINT,
                MASTER_KEY, ConnectionPolicy.GetDefault(),
                ConsistencyLevel.Session);

        User user = new User();
        user.setId("testuser");
        user = documentClient.createUser("dbs/db", user, null).getResource();

        Permission permission = new Permission();
        permission.setResourceLink("dbs/db/colls/coll");
        permission.setId("pertest");
        permission.setPermissionMode(PermissionMode.All);

        permission = documentClient.createPermission(user.getSelfLink(), permission, null).getResource();

        System.out.println(permission.getToken());
    }
}
```

Or you could do this job via REST API. Then replace the `master key` with `resource token` in your Mongoose client side.

Comment: I think you missed the point. I know how to generate resource token however it seems there is no way to use the token when connecting to CosmosDB using Mongoose library. In my experience you cannot simply replace master key with resource token.

Comment: @begie All right. I will test mongoose lib to connect to cosmos db with Resource Token.

Comment: Anyone tried to test the option to connect via mongodb client with resource token?